# Is it advisable for a Mexican citizen to apply for a TN visa while being in Canada?

Tags: usa, canada, mexico

So the situation is that a company is interested on hiring me, as far as I can tell it is possible to apply for a TN visa while being legally in Canada (which is the situation), but I also heard that the consulate might not be able to verify my information to do so, how accurate is this?

Comment: Why are you in Canada, what is your status there, and how long have you been there?

Comment: I've been in Canada for almost two years now as a student, and as I said a company wants to hire me, but it isn't possible for me to come back to my home country for a while, it's worth mentioning that I've been in the county legally all this time.

Comment: After I answered this question, I realized that it is here on [Travel.SE], where it is off topic, rather than on [Expatriates.SE], where it belongs.  I therefore voted to close it.  It now has three more close votes, so four out of the five needed for it to be closed.  You can use the "flag" link to ask a moderator to migrate it.  It might also get migrated on a moderator's own initiative.  You'll have to create a new account on the Expats, but if you do (and link it to this account, which is the default), then your new account should own the migrated question over there.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I'll do that later when I get the chance

Answer (score 2):

As someone who has resided in Canada for nearly two years, you are probably best advised to apply in Canada in any case.  A US consulate in Mexico would have more trouble verifying your information from the last two years, after all, than will one in Canada.

Here's what the US Department of State has to say about it, at [Visas for Canadian and Mexican NAFTA Professional Workers](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/employment/visas-canadian-mexican-nafta-professional-workers.html):

> You should schedule an appointment for your visa interview at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate in the country where you live. You may schedule your interview at another U.S. Embassy or Consulate, but be aware that it may be more difficult to qualify for a visa outside of the country where you live.

You live in Canada.  You should apply in Canada.

Comment: That's reasonable, I think I should discuss it further with my employers

Comment: @JavierCabreraGonzález why is your employer involved in deciding where you will apply for the visa?

Comment: I'm applying for NAFTA worker visa and they are sponsoring me

Comment: @JavierCabreraGonzález I understand that, but it shouldn't matter to them where you submit the application.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question, they are worried that if I apply in other country than my own my visa application would be rejected, that's why.

Comment: @JavierCabreraGonzález but why does it matter what they think?  It's *your* application. They only have to provide some supporting material.  *You* have to live with the consequences if it is rejected.  Tell them that the state department recommends applying in the *place of residence* (I'll add a link in a moment).  Tell them to retain an immigration lawyer if they're concerned that you're making the wrong decision.

Comment: Well if you have a link for that you would actually help me a lot, and I'll make sure to mention the lawyer part, thank you.

Comment: @JavierCabreraGonzález I edited the answer 15 minutes before you posted that comment.  If you haven't reloaded the page, there should be a banner you can click at the top of the answer.  Alternatively, you can reload the page.  If the reference doesn't seem adequate to you for some reason, please let me know why, and I'll see if I can find a better one.  Also, my tone is perhaps not the best tone to be taken with a prospective employer.  I wouldn't recommend actually "telling them they should" do anything; instead, ask whether it would make them feel better about it, or something like that.